# Apache Flink: InvalidProgramException: Table program cannot be compiled

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple program with a DataStream of Avro objects from which I want to extract a single String field. I convert the `DataStream` into a `Table` and run a query with a simple projection on it.

```
val kinesisConsumer = new FlinkKinesisConsumer(streamName, new UnifiedEventDeserializationSchema, consumerConfig)
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
implicit val typeInfo = TypeInformation.of(classOf[UnifiedEvent])
val kinesisStream = env.addSource(kinesisConsumer)
val tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)
tableEnv.registerDataStream("table1", kinesisStream);
val query = "SELECT nd_key FROM table1"
val result = tableEnv.sql(query)
tableEnv.toAppendStream[org.apache.avro.util.Utf8](result).print()
env.execute()
```

When I execute the program, I get the following exception:

> 11/29/2017 16:07:36   Source: Custom Source -> from:
>   (accepted_cohort_id, admin_id, after_submission, amount_paid,
>   anonymous_id, application_id, atom_key, bd_group_key, biz_geo,
>   braavos_purchase_id, category, cohort_id, concept_key, concept_rank,
>   context, context_campaign, context_experiment, coupon_code,
>   course_key, course_rank, cta_destination, cta_location, cta_message,
>   cta_type, currency, decision_group_id, device_browser, device_os,
>   device_os_version, device_type, duration, evaluation_id, event_type,
>   fin_geo, in_collaboration_with, lab_id, lab_rank, label, lesson_key,
>   lesson_rank, locale, max_pause_duration, message, message_id,
>   module_key, module_rank, nd_key, nd_unit_id, nd_unit_rank,
>   new_cohort_id, notification_id, num_concepts_completed,
>   num_interactions, num_lessons_completed, old_cohort_id, part_key,
>   part_rank, pause_duration, pause_reason, payment_plan,
>   payment_provider, points_earned, points_possible, price, price_sheet,
>   product_key, product_type, provider_charge_id, provider_refund_id,
>   quiz_type, referrer, refund_amount, requested_cohort_id, results,
>   scholarship_group_key, search_term, skill_level, subscription_id,
>   suspension_length, suspension_reason, technology, timestamp,
>   total_concepts, total_lessons, total_time_sec, type, unenroll_reason,
>   user_id, user_locale, user_response, variant, version, workspace_id,
>   workspace_session, workspace_type) -> select: (nd_key) -> to: Utf8 ->
>   Sink: Unnamed(5/8) switched to FAILED 
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Table program
>   cannot be compiled. This is a bug. Please file an issue.  at
>   org.apache.flink.table.codegen.Compiler$class.compile(Compiler.scala:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.table.runtime.CRowOutputMapRunner.compile(CRowOutputMapRunner.scala:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.table.runtime.CRowOutputMapRunner.open(CRowOutputMapRunner.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
>     at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: Line 790, Column 15:
>   Assignment conversion not possible from type "java.lang.CharSequence"
>   to type "org.apache.avro.util.Utf8"   at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:11672)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.assignmentConversion(UnitCompiler.java:10528)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:2534)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$2600(UnitCompiler.java:212)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$6.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$6.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:1443)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.Java$LocalVariableDeclarationStatement.accept(Java.java:3348)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:1443)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileStatements(UnitCompiler.java:1523)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:3052)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMethods(UnitCompiler.java:1313)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileDeclaredMethods(UnitCompiler.java:1286)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:785)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:436)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$400(UnitCompiler.java:212)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:390)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$2.visitPackageMemberClassDeclaration(UnitCompiler.java:385)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.Java$PackageMemberClassDeclaration.accept(Java.java:1405)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:385)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileUnit(UnitCompiler.java:357)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:234)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.compileToClassLoader(SimpleCompiler.java:446)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:213)
>     at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:204)
>     at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:80)    at
>   org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:75)     at
>   org.apache.flink.table.codegen.Compiler$class.compile(Compiler.scala:33)
>     ... 8 more

Answer (score 0):

The field `nd_key` of the Avro object is of type `java.lang.CharSequence` and handled as such by the SQL query.

By calling `toAppendStream[org.apache.avro.util.Utf8]`, you request that the result of the query should be converted into a `DataStream[Utf8]`. However, Flink cannot automatically convert `CharSequence` to `Utf8`.

Try to change `toAppendStream[org.apache.avro.util.Utf8]` to `toAppendStream[java.lang.CharSequence]`.

Which Flink version are you using?